# why does rails update my carrierwave image even if I don't update that attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using carrierwave_direct to upload files to S3. I have a photo model which includes the image attribute that is mounted by carrierwave and has some other attributes like copies. In my application it is possible to upload a photo and later update these other attributes. What I don't understand is why rails updates the image attribute even though it is not updated. See for example the log below where I only updated the copies attribute (see params). However, in the update to the DB rails updates the image column as well.

```
Started PATCH "/photos/1275" for 192.168.2.100 at 2014-06-20 00:53:51 +0300
Processing by PhotosController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "photo"=>{"copies"=>"2"}, "photo_id"=>"1275"}
  Photo Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."id" = ? LIMIT 1 [["id", "1275"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Photo Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1275]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "photos" SET "copies" = ?, "image" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "photos"."id" = 1275  [["copies", 2], ["image", "593c9f04-b5b1-4150-ae76-74eed8b0d3ea/foto%201.JPG"], ["updated_at", Fri, 20 Jun 2014 00:53:51 EEST +03:00]]
```

In my case this causes me trouble, because there can be a situation where initially an image is saved in the DB as '/photo 1.jpg' (not url encoded) and after updating another attribute it will be changed to '/photo%201.jpg' (url encoded).

I tried to prevent this behavior by doing something like below, but that does not seem to work.

```
before_update do
  self.key = URI.decode(key)
end
```

I would appreciate any insight in why this is happening and/or how to solve this.

Thanks!